# add a column value before saving item to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say user submits a form (creates new item in his account).

Before it goes to database - I want to do this:

```
params[:user] => current_user.id
# make a note of who is the owner of the item
# without people seing this or being able to change it themselves
# and only after that to save it to database
```

What's the best way to do it?

All I see in controller is this:

```
def create
    @item = Item.new(params[:item])
    ...
end
```

And I'm not sure how to change values under params[:item]

(current_user.id is Devise variable)

Tried to do this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :set_user

    protected

    def set_user
        self.user = current_user.id unless self.user
    end

end
```

And got an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user'
```

Comment: I don't know your exact setup with `current_user`, but what if you change `current_user.id` to `User.current_user.id`?

Comment: @shioyama `current_user` is a variable made available by devise, and it's the currently logged in user, not a method on the User model.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't realize it was set by devise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
def create
    @item = Item.new(params[:item])
    @item.user = current_user
    #...
end
```

You're getting an `undefined local variable or method current_user` error as `current_user` is not available in the model context, only controller and views.

Comment: Thanks! I could have guessed